# Fixing corrupted .ibd file (MySQL table) with Windows Restore

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, mysql, system-restore

I'm looking after a call centre (center for American fellows :) ). We recently installed VoIP based telephone system.

One of many components of the new system is a logging software. The software provider supplied their own "server" for this purpose. In fact, the machine has Windows 10 Pro installed rather than a server OS.

The database technology, behind the logging software itself, is MySQL. Recently, two of the .ibd files (MySQL tables) have been corrupted. The support spent ages on the server and, although, they haven't fixed the issue, they came up with the theory that this happened during the Windows update.

The system is so new that I haven't got to sorting the backup solution for it yet, so, according to the support, we lost the data.

Although, this is not business critical, it is still painful.

As far as I understand Windows creates a restore point before each update. My question is - will the Windows restore activity return the .ibd files to the previous state?

Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of the ibd files and using MySQL tools, then tried loadidng mysqld with innodb_force_recovery = 1 (so you can dump the data - don't do anything active on it) ?  Note that if a value of 1 doesnt work you can try progressively higher values, with corresponding likelyhood of data loss.

Comment: It is support that deals with this, so I am not sure what they did and what they didn't try. I can see they installed MySQL Workbench, so probably tried similar approach. I just wanted to know whether the Windows restore activity will return the .ibd files to the previous state.